# How to install Android SDK and eclipse in windows xp ?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am stuck in between installing Android SDK eclipse in my windows xp sp3 pc. The android SDK is not getting installed in eclipse. What could be the problem? I don't mind uninstalling eclipse and starting the installation again. Is there any step by step guide to do this?

Comment: better watch given video link n update ur android sdk :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the instructions posted in the android page [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html), there is explained step by step what you should do.

I don't think the SDK is OS dependent, so it should be the same for all windows operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

### Setting Up the Environment For Android For Eclipse

Download the Android SDK corresponding to the system which you are using

For Windows - http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-windows.zip

```
           http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r15-windows.exe
```

For Mac OS - http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-macosx.zip

For Linux - http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz

1) Prepare your development computer and ensure it meets the system requirements.

```
a) Need to install the JDK, if you don't have it already.(http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)

b) If you will be developing in Eclipse with the Android Development Tools (ADT) Plugin(http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

  The "Eclipse Classic" version is recommended. Otherwise, a Java or RCP version of Eclipse is recommended.
```

2) Install the SDK starter package .

```
   a) If you downloaded a .zip or .tgz package (instead of the SDK installer), unpack it to a safe location on your machine. 
  By default, the SDK files are unpacked into a directory named android-sdk-<machine-platform>.

   b) If you downloaded the Windows installer (.exe file), run it now and it will check whether the proper Java SE Development 
  Kit(JDK) is installed (installing it, if necessary), then install the SDK Tools into a default location (which you can modify).

   c) Make a note of the name and location of the SDK directory on your system—you will need to refer to the SDK directory later, 
  when setting up the ADT plugin and when using the SDK tools from the command line.
```

3) Install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse (if you'll be developing in Eclipse, You can download the ADT plugin from
          http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing).

```
   a) Follow these steps to download the ADT plugin and install it in your Eclipse environment.

        i) Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....

        ii) Click Add, in the top-right corner.

        iii) In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location: 
        https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
        (If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

        iv) In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.

        v) In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next. 

        vi) Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish. 

b) Configuring the ADT Plugin - the next step is to modify your ADT preferences in Eclipse to point to the Android SDK directory:

    i) Select Window > Preferences... to open the Preferences panel (Mac OS X: Eclipse > Preferences).

    ii) Select Android from the left panel.

    iii) For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate your downloaded SDK directory. Click Apply, then OK.
```

4) Add Android platforms and other components to your SDK.

```
   a) You can launch the Android SDK and AVD Manager in one of the following ways:

        i) From within Eclipse, select Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager.

        ii) On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory.

        iii) On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the Android SDK, then execute: android

   b) To download components, use the graphical UI of the Android SDK and AVD Manager to browse the SDK repository and select new or
  updated components, The Android SDK and AVD Manager installs the selected components in your SDK environment
```

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple to install sdk 
1. download android-sdk_r16-windows.zip from
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html 
2. extract it and double click on SDK manager. 
3. download/install required API packages. 
4. download latest AVD go to elipse's Help menu and click on install new software.
5. go for zip file and browse the downloaded AVD .zip file.
6. then go to eclipse's Menu windows/preferences/android 
7. select your sdk's location. press ok.